# Can't insert data into db sqLite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

i can't insert in right way some data from a listview to my database sqLite. I have a class with my Items:

```
public class Corsa
 {
    private int id;
    public String oraPartenza;
    public String oraArrivo;
    public String partenza;
    public String arrivo;
    public String codiceLinea;
    public String codiceCorsa;
    public String tipoCorsa;
    public String linkDettaglio;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    /*@Override
    public String toString() {
        return oraPartenza + partenza + oraArrivo + arrivo;
    }*/

    public Corsa() {

    }

    public Corsa(String partenza, String arrivo, String oraPartenza, String oraArrivo) {
        super();
        this.arrivo = arrivo;
        this.partenza = partenza;
        this.oraPartenza = oraPartenza;
        this.oraArrivo = oraArrivo;
    }

    // partenza
    public String getPartenza() {
        return partenza;
    }
    public void setPartenza(String partenza) {
        this.partenza = partenza;
    }

    // arrivo
    public String getArrivo() {
        return arrivo;
    }
    public void setArrivo(String arrivo) {
        this.arrivo = arrivo;
    }

    // ora partenza
    public String getOraPartenza() {
        return oraPartenza;
    }
    public void setOraPartenza(String oraPartenza) {
        this.oraPartenza = oraPartenza;
    }

    // ora arrivo
    public String getOraArrivo() {
        return oraArrivo;
    }
    public void setOraArrivo(String oraArrivo) {
        this.oraArrivo = oraArrivo;
    }
}
```

This class is used to retrive the information from web and put the datas in a listview. Works perfectly and i have a listview with a custom adapter in which show every data how i want. Now i would take the data from that listview and create anothe list with, for example, only "Partenza" and "Arrivo" from the item selected and put them in. The helper i created:

```
public class SqlHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //Do un nome al DB
    private static final String DB_NOME = "PREF";
    private SqlHelper mMioDbHelper = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    // variabili x inserimento
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_PARTENZA = "partenza";
    private static final String KEY_ORA_PARTENZA = "oraPartenza";
    private static final String KEY_ARRIVO = "arrivo";
    private static final String KEY_ORA_ARRIVO = "oraArrivo";

    String TABLE_PREFERITI = "preferiti";
    /**
     * Numero della versione del database.
     * 
     * La numerazione della vesione del database deve iniziare dal numero 1.
     * Quando viene specificata una nuova versione android useguirà la funzione onUpgrade.
     */
    private static final int DB_VERSIONE = 1;

    public SqlHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NOME, null, DB_VERSIONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        /*
         * creazione della tabella PREFERITI
         */
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE preferiti"; 
        sql += "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,";
        sql += "partenza TEXT NOT NULL,";
        sql += "arrivo TEXT,";
        sql += "oraPartenza TEXT,";
        sql += "oraArrivo TEXT);";


        //Eseguo la query
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ DB_NOME);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addCorsa(Corsa corsaDett, int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_ID, corsaDett.getId());
        values.put(KEY_PARTENZA, corsaDett.getPartenza());
        values.put(KEY_ORA_PARTENZA, corsaDett.getOraPartenza());
        values.put(KEY_ARRIVO, corsaDett.getArrivo());
        values.put(KEY_ORA_ARRIVO, corsaDett.getOraArrivo());

        // insert valori
        db.insert(TABLE_PREFERITI, null, values);

        // chiudo il db
        db.close();
        Log.d("addCorsa", corsaDett.toString());
    }

    //Get All Corse
    public List<Corsa> getAllCorse() {
        List<Corsa> corse = new ArrayList<Corsa>();

        // 1. build the query
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PREFERITI;

        // 2. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        // 3. go over each row, build book and add it to list
        Corsa corsaAll = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                corsaAll = new Corsa();
                corsaAll.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                corsaAll.setPartenza((cursor.getString(1)));
                corsaAll.setArrivo((cursor.getString(2)));
                corsaAll.setOraPartenza(((cursor.getString(3))));
                corsaAll.setOraArrivo((cursor.getString(4)));

                // Add book to books
                corse.add(corsaAll);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        Log.d("getAllBooks()", corse.toString());

        // return books
        return corse;
    }

    //Deleting single row
    public void deleteRow(Corsa corsa) {

        // 1. get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // 2. delete

        db.delete(TABLE_PREFERITI,
                  KEY_ID + " = ?",
                  new String[] { String.valueOf(corsa.getId())}
                  );

        // 3. close
        db.close();

        Log.d("deleteCorsa", corsa.toString());

    }

}
```

this is the onlongClick in the item:

```
mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){

                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> p1, View p2, int p3, long p4)
                {
                    addToDb(mListView.toString());
                    return true;
                }           


            });
```

and the method addToDB:

```
protected void addToDb (String input) {
        value++;
        mMioDbHelper = new SqlHelper(this);
        mMioDbHelper.addCorsa(new Corsa(input, input, input, input), value);
        corsa = mMioDbHelper.getAllCorse();

    }
```

to retrive the datas in the other activity i do in this way:

```
mMioDbHelper = new SqlHelper(getActivity());
        list = mMioDbHelper.getAllCorse();

        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            listaPreferiti.setAdapter(null);
        } else {
            adapter = new PreferitiItemAdapter(getActivity(), list);
            listaPreferiti.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
```

Now..it saves the datas but it display them not every item in the position of the adapter but seems it takes the entire string `oraPartenza " / " partenza " " + oraArrivo " / " arrivo;` and repeats the entire line in the adapter. Something is wrong in the insert?

Answer (score 0):

Your addToDb() function isn't correct. It's important to recognize that mListView.toString() is only going to give you a single, long string.

When you call mMioDbHelper.addCorsa(new Corsa(input, input, input, input), value), you're essentially creating a new Corsa with every variable set to mListView.toString().

What you need to do is parse mListView.toString and get each piece of information individually, then create a new Corsa.

So, your addToDb should look like something below, where each input corresponds to some variable of Corsa:

```
protected void addToDb (String input1, String input2, String input3, String input4) {
    value++;
    mMioDbHelper = new SqlHelper(this);
    mMioDbHelper.addCorsa(new Corsa(input1, input2, input3, input4), value);
    corsa = mMioDbHelper.getAllCorse();
}
```

Also, why aren't you using listview.getItemAtPosition()?

Edit: Also, you should try to set your id to AUTO INCREMENT. It will be easier than you having to increment value each time.

Edit 2:

```
protected void addToDb (Corsa c) {
    mMioDbHelper = new SqlHelper(this);
    mMioDbHelper.addCorsa(c);
    corsa = mMioDbHelper.getAllCorse();
}
```

Basically, your list.getItemAtPosition should return an instance of Corsa, which you pass through to addToDb().

Comment: Ok, but in this way the method addCorse in the helper must be changed right?

Comment: So in the onClick will be: `addToDb(input.toString(), input.toString(), input.toString(), input.toString());`?

Comment: Can you please help me to finish the project? I could send you an email.. Thanks

Comment: The list seems empty now.. listen to me.. can You write me bere: dellai.davide@gmail.com ?